# how to sort data when I get foregin key objects

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data jpa. I have `client` table and `group` table, the relation between these two entities is many-yo-many,corresponing table is `rel_client_group`. The `group` entity has a field `clients`.`clients` type is `List<Client>`. I can get all groups with the `findAll` method.But I want to sort the client data in the `clients` field. My `rel_client_group` has three field `client_id`,`group_id`,`index`.I want to sort by index. I can use @OrderBy("clientId ASC") to sort by clientId.But `clientId` is a client's field.Now I want to sort by `rel_client_group` index field.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,

I am assuming your entities

```java
@Entity
... others
public class Client {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long clientId;

    ... other fields

}
```

```java
@Entity
... others
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long groupId;

    ... other fields
}
```

For maintaining the `ManyToMany` relationship between above two we are introduction a pivot table named `rel_client_group` with following fields

- clientId
- groupId
- index

I am assuming in the `rel_client_group` table, `clientId` & `groupId` are composite primary key / unique key.

So for `rel_client_group` defining the primary key introducing the `@Embeddable`

```java
@Embeddable
public class ClassGroupId {
    
    @Column(name = "clientId")
    public Long clientId;

    @Column( name = "groupId")
    public Long groupId;

}
```

Now defining entity for the pivot table

```java
@Entity
... others
public class RelClientGroup {

    @EmbeddedId
    public ClassGroupId classGroupId;

    @Column(name = "index")
    public Long index;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("clientId")
    public Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    public Group group;
}
```

Now modify the `Group` entity as follows

```java
@Entity
... others
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long groupId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CASCADE.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<RelClientGroup> clients = new ArrayList<RelClientGroup>();

    ... other fields
}
```

Now your jpql for fetching `groups` with `clients`, sorted against the `index` would be

```
SELECT g FROM Group g
INNER JOIN FETCH g.clients relClientGroup
INNER JOIN FETCH relClientGroup.client
ORDER BY relClientGroup.index <ASC / DESC according to your need.>
```

All credits goes to @Vladimir [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/).